# Debian 10 can't apt update on debian servers, but I can ping it. (other sources are fine...)

Tags: debian, networking, apt

I can't apt update on debian 10. All servers from debian return an error. I can ping them, but I can't apt update or apt-get install.

My sources.list :

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib


deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib
```

The result of apt update :

```
conga@mcusys-00001:~$ sudo apt update
Atteint :1 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian buster InRelease
Atteint :2 https://cli.github.com/packages stable InRelease                                                                                            
Err :3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease                                                                                                   
  Connexion à debian.map.fastlydns.net: 80 (151.101.18.132) impossible, délai de connexion dépassé Impossible de se connecter à deb.debian.org:http :
Err :4 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease                                                         
  Impossible de se connecter à deb.debian.org:http :
Err :5 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports InRelease                                       
  Impossible de se connecter à deb.debian.org:http :
Err :6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease                           
  Connexion à debian.map.fastlydns.net: 80 (199.232.174.132) impossible, délai de connexion dépassé Connexion à security.debian.org: 80 (151.101.66.132) impossible, délai de connexion dépassé Connexion à security.debian.org: 80 (151.101.194.132) impossible, délai de connexion dépassé Connexion à security.debian.org: 80 (151.101.130.132) impossible, délai de connexion dépassé Connexion à security.debian.org: 80 (151.101.2.132) impossible, délai de connexion dépassé
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait                
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
4 paquets peuvent être mis à jour. Exécutez « apt list --upgradable » pour les voir.
W: Impossible de récupérer http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease  Connexion à debian.map.fastlydns.net: 80 (151.101.18.132) impossible, délai de connexion dépassé Impossible de se connecter à deb.debian.org:http :
W: Impossible de récupérer http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/buster/updates/InRelease  Connexion à debian.map.fastlydns.net: 80 (199.232.174.132) impossible, délai de connexion dépassé Connexion à security.debian.org: 80 (151.101.66.132) impossible, délai de connexion dépassé Connexion à security.debian.org: 80 (151.101.194.132) impossible, délai de connexion dépassé Connexion à security.debian.org: 80 (151.101.130.132) impossible, délai de connexion dépassé Connexion à security.debian.org: 80 (151.101.2.132) impossible, délai de connexion dépassé
W: Impossible de récupérer http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/InRelease  Impossible de se connecter à deb.debian.org:http :
W: Impossible de récupérer http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-backports/InRelease  Impossible de se connecter à deb.debian.org:http :
W: Le téléchargement de quelques fichiers d'index a échoué, ils ont été ignorés, ou les anciens ont été utilisés à la place.
```

As you could see, docker and github works fine. :-/

My resolv.conf

```
# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Ping to deb.debian.org :

```
conga@mcusys-00001:~$ ping deb.debian.org
PING debian.map.fastlydns.net (151.101.18.132) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 151.101.18.132 (151.101.18.132): icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=66.4 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.18.132 (151.101.18.132): icmp_seq=2 ttl=47 time=48.6 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.18.132 (151.101.18.132): icmp_seq=3 ttl=47 time=55.7 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.18.132 (151.101.18.132): icmp_seq=4 ttl=47 time=61.7 ms
^C
--- debian.map.fastlydns.net ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 9ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 48.645/58.101/66.374/6.657 ms
```

And that's fine too. So, I don't get what could be wrong. Any idea ?
thanks.
Xavier.

Comment: Shouldn't all those `http` actually be `https` these days?

Comment: @roaima no, see [the configuration snippet on deb.debian.org](https://deb.debian.org/).

Comment: You could try changing mirrors, eg using http://ftp.fr.debian.org/ to see if it works better (won't help for security.debian.org) to rule out some kind of issues.

Comment: @StephenKitt fair enough

Comment: @roaima it’s a legitimate question, there’s a better explanation somewhere but I can’t remember where right now — basically TLS doesn’t offer any significant advantage when accessing a Debian repository, not even privacy (because the files being downloaded can be inferred just from the transfer sizes).

Comment: @StephenKitt I wondered because there are two IP addresses that the OP can't access. If it was one I'd have suggested the server. With two unreachable that becomes a less likely scenario

Comment: What happens if you run these two commands? `wget http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/InRelease` and `wget https://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/InRelease`

Comment: @EduardoTrápani the wget don't work .... :/

I'm getting this message :  

Résolution de deb.debian.org (deb.debian.org)… 199.232.174.132, 2a04:4e42:4::644
Connexion à deb.debian.org (deb.debian.org)|199.232.174.132|:80… échec : Connexion terminée par expiration du délai d'attente.
Connexion à deb.debian.org (deb.debian.org)|2a04:4e42:4::644|:80… échec : Ne peut attribuer l'adresse demandée.
Nouvel essai.

Comment: @A.B I tried as you say. But no succes. 
After reading yours comments, I tried to curl and wget some web page and that's work only with https. 
I'm wondering what can block http request... :/

Comment: Running some fancy intercepting application in a container or elsewhere you forgot about?

Comment: @A.B, yes ! This computer is behind a microtik with specific set-up. I'm pretty sure now the problem come from there. I'm in touch with network guy.
Thanks !